# Rails cannot load such file -- magazine/rinda_ring_finger_patch (LoadError)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bundler

Whenever I use the command "bundle exec guard" (for using the bundled gem guard) I get this error:

```
$ bundle exec guard
15:17:57 - INFO - Guard is using Notifu to send notifications.
15:17:57 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
15:17:57 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
15:17:57 - INFO - Starting Spork for RSpec
Using RSpec, Rails
cannot load such file -- magazine/rinda_ring_finger_patch (LoadError)
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32/
lib/spork/run_strategy/magazine.rb:20:in `require'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32/
lib/spork/run_strategy/magazine.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32/
lib/spork/run_strategy.rb:48:in `require'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32/
lib/spork/run_strategy.rb:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32/
lib/spork/run_strategy.rb:48:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32/
lib/spork/run_strategy.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32/
lib/spork/runner.rb:74:in `run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32/
lib/spork/runner.rb:10:in `run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32/
bin/spork:10:in `<top (required)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/spork:23:in `load'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/spork:23:in `<main>'
```

This also happens when I load the rspec command, and the root cause seems to be that it can't load a certain file inside the magazine file, which I have located at the location

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\spork-1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32\lib\spork\run_strategy\magazine .

This is the contents of the folder: http://puu.sh/5Ixw5.jpg

Any ideas are welcome, and just a side note - for some reason, the command "bundle update" resolves dependencies for an indefinite period of time, and at one point I left it on all night. Nothing happened.

Comment: You might have a circular dependency if bundle update was stuck. Try doing gem install on magazine and see if any errors popup

Comment: This is the last few lines from running "bundle install":

Using selenium-webdriver (2.37.0)
Using spork-rails (4.0.0)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.8)
Using turbolinks (1.3.1)
Using uglifier (2.3.1)
Using wdm (0.1.0)
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the group production were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.